# Java Generics Cast Error

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

corresponding to the title, my problem is to get the array-length of an generic array, which is inside an instance of an class, which has been initialized with this generic type.
When i want to get the length of my array (ak.array.length), java throws this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at Testclass.main(Testclass.java:15)

So where is my fault in this code?
Thanks in advance

```
public class Testclass {

    static class ArrayKeeper<T> {
        protected T[] array;

        public ArrayKeeper() {
            array = (T[])new Object[5];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a new instance of inner class ArrayKepper (type String)
        Testclass.ArrayKeeper<String> ak = new Testclass.ArrayKeeper<String>();
        System.out.println(ak.array.length); //cast error here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this line:

```
array = (T[]) new Object[5];
```

That's not the way to create a generic array, you're creating an `Object[]` and not a `String[]` as you intended. You can not create an `Object[]` and then cast it to any type you want, you have to create an array of the correct class. Try this instead:

```
public ArrayKeeper(Class<T> clazz, int size) {
    array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```

And then, when you need to instantiate an `ArrayKeeper` do this:

```
Testclass.ArrayKeeper<String> ak =
    new Testclass.ArrayKeeper<String>(String.class, 5);
```

Comment: Meh.  Better than the reflection-based approach is just to hide the casts with an API.  Look at e.g. the implementation of `ArrayList` in Java: it's backed by a plain old `Object[]` and objects are cast on calls to `get(int)` and the like.  Just avoid _exposing_ the casts, and you'll be set.

Comment: Reflection is slow and requires you to pass around and track lots of perfectly redundant `Class` objects.  The best option of all is probably to use a `List` instead of an array, but failing that, cluttering your API with passing around `Class` objects is just awkward.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Reflection is _not_ as slow as it used to be (that's a common misconception), and besides, how do you know if this is going to be slow if you don't know the intended usage, and have not profiled it yet? W.r.t. passing around Class objects, that's a very common idiom, in use all over the place in Java's API itself.

Comment: In what parts of the Java APIs?  Nowhere in the collections framework, albeit with the notable (and deserving) exception of `EnumMap` and `EnumSet`.  I'll...grant that reflection is much faster than it used to be, and I believe the `Array.newInstance` idiom actually ends up getting used in `AbstractCollection.toArray(T[])`.  But...if you insist, here's another argument: what if `T` itself is a generic type?  The approach you describe in this answer stops you from using a generic `T`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman read the [FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#Topic8) first, please.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  But `new ArrayKeeper<List<String>>(List.class, 5)` will type-error; it'll expect a `Class<List<String>>`.  In that case, your only alternative is `(Class) List.class`, which triggers an unchecked cast warning...in which case, we're not getting any benefit over the API-wrapping approach anyway.

Comment: In any event, I'm not seeing how the reflection-based approach adds any value.  Even if it's "a common idiom," it's an idiom with no benefit at all: it just adds gratuitous boilerplate to what can be a perfectly simple API.

Comment: That Angelika Langer article is great but I think it's annoying when people just drop a link to it instead of their own intelligent response.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement the `length` getter in `ArrayKeeper`, just because you can't cast an `Object[]` to a `String[]`, and calling `ak.array` does try to do that cast.

Comment: For my understanding: Doesn't array = (T[])new Object[5]; perform a cast already?

Comment: Nope.  Due to type erasure at runtime, no actual casting occurs at that point.  (After type erasure, `T` becomes `Object`.)